# Xcode 9 Ios11 -> UITableViewController won't show anything

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a big problem and I searched already but didn't find anything.
All worked and then I put this code in my `viewDidLoad()` of the class UITableViewController.

```
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: self.view.frame)
    let image = UIImage(named: "sample")!
    imageView.image = image
    self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView
```

If I run it, it just shows the background and some lines from the cells but no text:

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2VbK.png)

Comment: your code puts the image on the view, not on the tableView. If you want to put it on the tableView, you need to put it on the cell.

Comment: @MuhammadFauziMasykur But `self.view` is the table view if this is a `UITableViewController`.

Comment: I donät think it's correct to add custom subviews into UITableView...

Comment: Is the background of your TableView and TableViewCells set to clear?

Comment: yes I set it all to clear

Comment: Ok it worked now, I just fergot to change in the UITableViewController.swift to change the sections and rows.